# Rubymine rspec test output not understood by rubymine run console

Tags: rubymine

Whenever I run rspec it always shows tests passed: 0 of x tests even though all of them pass. On the console it also says no tests were found. The rspec output is also pretty hard to decipher because it has a lot of teamcity formatting output. See below picture for reference.

[image]

I am running this via docker-compose up, run and exec with the same results. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: There's a similar issue on the RubyMine's tracker (probably created by you) so it's better to investigate the problem there. Leaving a link for others who face it:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-31852